# How to fetch buybox name using amazon mws api?

Tags: api, amazon-mws

Is there any method or report which provide buybox name of particular ASIN by using amazon mws api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscribe to the [AnyOffChanged](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_NotificationType.html) notification, you will receive in real-time a list of the top 20 offers for any ASIN you are currently selling, when there is a pricing change.  Part of the data that is returned is the name of the Buy Box owner (as well as the owners for all other offers).   We use this in conjunction with our repricing service.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon returns the name of the seller who owns Buybox if the seller is Amazon. :)